# Tcl Script OR Perl?

Tags: perl, tcl

I wish to replace the following verilog code by using scripting.

```verilog
assign x0 = in0 + in7;
```

I wish to search for the "+" sign above and replace the whole line with the line below:

```verilog
KSA_32 U1(.A(in0), .B(in7), .Sum(x0));
```

any suggestion and sample script on this?

Comment: Probably you need to design a module called KSA_32 which has inputs A and B, and an output Sum. Then you need to assign Sum = A + B; Hope you know what I mean.

Comment: If you asked the question in a better way, you would get  better answers, but we cannot know your system and design before you describe it.

Comment: @AdhamzhonShukurov The module is ready, I need to instantiate the module using tcl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Verilog file is able to fit comfortably in memory, you can simply do:

```
# Read in the file
set f [open $verilogfile r]
set contents [read $f]
close $f

# Perform the transform across the whole contents
regsub -all {assign\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)\s*\+\s*(\w+);} $contents \
        {KSA_32 U1(.A(\2), .B(\3), .Sum(\1));} contents

# Write the results out to a new file (different filename so you can check the results by hand)
set f [open $verilogfile.new w]
puts -nonewline $f $contents
close $f
```

The first and third block are standard Tcl patterns for file manipulation. The second is a standard regular expression substitution, which I made by taking what you asked for and applying guesses for what are templates. Note that the literal `+` needs to be escaped, and spaces are best matched as `\s+` or `\s*`.

Comment: Sorry about this, if my verilog file is available on a directory, what should I do?

Comment: @e2g05Ricky I don't think I understand your question, but “use the full pathname” would seem like a sensible option?

Comment: Is the tcl above able to read many file, editing those file and saved to original named?